# Can an XOR linked list be implemented in C++ without causing undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, language-lawyer, xor

An **[XOR linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list)** is a modified version of a normal doubly-linked list in which each node stores just one "pointer" instead of two.  That "pointer" is composed of the XOR of the next and previous pointers.  To traverse the list, two pointers are needed - one to the current node and one to the next or previous node.  To traverse forward, the previous node's address is XORed with the "pointer" stored in the current node, revealing the true "next" pointer.

The C++ standard causes a bunch of operations on pointers and integers to result in undefined behavior - for example, you cannot guarantee that setting a particular bit in a number will not cause the hardware to trigger an interrupt, so in some cases the results of bit twiddling can be undefined.

My question is the following: is there a C++ implementation of an XOR linked list that does not result in undefined behavior?

Comment: A similar (but not the same) question is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531972/c-code-for-xor-linked-list

Comment: UB is not the "result" of an implementation.

Comment: @curiousguy That's a good point. Do you have a recommendation for a different way to word that sentence?

Comment: @templatetypedef The std can define some behavior as UB. An implementation can have unwanted, unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Is it definitely undefined behaviour to XOR pointers? Which part of the standard says this? Why does the language permit the use of the bitwise XOR operator on pointer types, if it always causes undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My question is the following: is there a C++ implementation of an XOR linked list that does not result in undefined behavior?

If by "is there an implementation" you mean "has it already been written" then I don't know. If you mean "is it possible to write one" then yes it is but there might be some caveats about portability.

You can bit-twiddle to your heart's content if you convert both pointers to `uintptr_t` before you start, and store that type in the node instead of a pointer. Bitwise operations on unsigned types never result in undefined behavior.

However, `uintptr_t` is an optional type and so it's not entirely portable. There is no requirement that a C++ implementation actually has an integer type capable of representing an address. If the implementation doesn't have `uintptr_t` then the code is permitted to compile with a diagnostic, in which case its behavior is outside the scope of the standard. Not sure whether you consider that an infringement of "without UB" or not. I mean, seriously, a compiler that allows code which uses undefined types? ;-)

To avoid `uintptr_t` I *think* that you could do your bit-twiddling on an array of `sizeof(node*)` unsigned chars instead. Pointers are POD types and so can be copied, spindled and mutilated provided that the object representation is restored to its original condition before being used as a pointer.

Note also that if your C++ implementation has a garbage collector, then convert-to-integer / xor / xor-back-again / convert-to-pointer doesn't necessary stop the object being collected (because it results in an "unsafely derived pointer"). So for portability you must *also* ensure that the resulting pointers are valid. Two ways to do this:

1. call `declare_reachable` on them.
2. Use an implementation with *relaxed pointer safety* (it is implementation-defined whether this is the case, and you can test for it with `get_pointer_safety()` bearing in mind that a relaxed implementation is allowed to falsely claim that it's strict).

You might think that there's a third way (albeit one that defeats the purpose of the XOR linked list unless you happen to have it anyway):

- keep a separate container of all the pointer values

*This is not guaranteed to work*. An unsafely derived pointer is invalid even if it happens to be equal to a safely-derived pointer (3.7.4.3/4). I was surprised too.

Comment: Beat me by 18 seconds, +1.

Comment: If you aren't careful, the resulting pointers will not be safely derived.  [`declare_reachable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/declare_reachable) might solve that with some care. (In C++11)

Comment: @Yakk: I was just writing the same thing.

Comment: @SteveJessop so, do you have to unreach them as well?  :)  Also note that this isn't just about garbage collection, but also leak detection.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Is `uintptr_t` really optional? I thought only the fixed/least/fast integer types were optional.

Comment: @GManNickG: that's what 18.4.1 says.

Comment: @Yakk: I don't think you're *required* to undeclare them reachable but yes, it's a leak if you don't. Knowing when you can undeclare them is a resource-management problem similar to knowing when to deallocate things, and I leave it as an exercise for the questioner ;-)

Comment: @GManNickG: An implementation might have 128-bit pointers but no integer types bigger than 64 bits, for example.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thanks for being my lookup engine. :)

Comment: "An unsafely derived pointer is invalid even if it happens to be equal to a safely-derived pointer (3.7.4.3/4)" I don't think 3.7.4.3/4 is the right reference for this, as 3.7.4.3 is "Any allocation and/or deallocation functions deﬁned in a C++ program, including the default versions in the library, shall conform to the semantics speciﬁed in 3.7.4.1 and 3.7.4.2" and there is no 3.7.4.4.

Comment: @Cornstalks: I mean `[basic.stc.dynamic.safety]`, I'm using N3337 which is the FDIS plus editorial changes. If the section numbering doesn't match the published standard then I'm probably going to get a lot of complaints as and when I refer to the changed sections on SO!

Comment: @SteveJessop: Ah, sorry, I was looking at paragraph 3 of 3.7.4 and missed 3.7.4's sub-sections. Silly me. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Also, +1 for finding and mentioning 3.7.4.3 paragraph 4. I never knew that.

Comment: @KeithThompson one can always implement a custom integral type, I suppose.