# Can we implement a doubly-linked list using a single pointer?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, logic

I want to use a structure like:

```
struct node {
   char[10] tag;
   struct node *next;
};
```

I want to use the above structure to create a doubly-linked list. Is that possible and if yes, then how I can achieve it?

Comment: Your accepted answer is C++ only. Please remove the C tag, as you seem looking for C++.

Comment: While the example was in C++ the core of the question and answer is the same for both.

Comment: If you detail the operations needed on your list - even better answers can be had.  The XOR approach does not provide "the ability to delete a node from the list knowing only its address or the ability to insert a new node before or after an existing node when knowing only the address of the existing node."  So unless you are giving up some feature of a doubly linked list, code cannot solve the issue with a single pointer/data.

Comment: <sarcasm>Good question, since the original doubly-linked list appears to be patented: [link](http://www.google.com/patents/US7028023#v=onepage&q=&f=false)  You wouldn't want to be accused of stealing someone else's intellectual property...</sarcasm>

Comment: You can trivially make a doubly linked list of length 2 ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but it's a dirty hack.

It's called *XOR linked list*. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list)

Each node stores a XOR of `next` and `prev` as a uintptr_t.

---

Here is an example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int num;
    uintptr_t ptr;
};

int main()
{
    Node *arr[4];
    // Here we create a new list.
    int num = 0;
    for (auto &it : arr)
    {
        it = new Node;
        it->num = ++num;
    }
    arr[0]->ptr =                     (uintptr_t)arr[1];
    arr[1]->ptr = (uintptr_t)arr[0] ^ (uintptr_t)arr[2];
    arr[2]->ptr = (uintptr_t)arr[1] ^ (uintptr_t)arr[3];
    arr[3]->ptr = (uintptr_t)arr[2];

    // And here we iterate over it
    Node *cur = arr[0], *prev = 0;
    do
    {
        std::cout << cur->num << ' ';
        prev = (Node *)(cur->ptr ^ (uintptr_t)prev);
        std::swap(cur, prev);
    }
    while (cur);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `1 2 3 4` as expected.

Comment: Nice trick, hadn't seen that before. You do need the previous or next node as well as the current node in order to traverse the list though.

Comment: Do it have any issue like performance or something else.

Comment: @Avi Yes, performance can be an issue. Normal double linked list is faster. You should use XOR linked list only if you need to keep memory usage *very* low.

Comment: @Avi If performance is a concern, the performance of a linked-list (single or double) or any linked structure in general heavily depends on the memory layout given to it by its memory allocator. Whether trees or linked lists, if you want to take the performance of such structures to the next level, you want to look at it from the standpoint of memory allocation, and getting back some of those contiguous qualities that arrays have which make them so well-suited for exploiting locality of reference.

Comment: How do you extract `next` and `prev` from `ptr` if you don't have one or the other?

Comment: @dbush You need pointers to **two** adjacent nodes. Then you can do this: `c_ptr = b_ptr->ptr ^ a_ptr;`

Comment: @Ike: A linked list is a data structure and has nothing to do with memory allocation. These are twwo completely different subjects.

Comment: Totally understand that -- but a linked list is a data structure which allocates per-node, which means a loss of control in memory layout, which typically translates in real-world cases (ex: especially if not all nodes are allocated in one go) to a loss in performance. To put "linked list and performance" in the same sentence is often an oxymoron unless we gain back that control over the memory layout, which is why I recommend to anyone who wants to use SLLs or DLLs in a very performance-critical context to look to the memory allocator, if the desire is to continue to use the same structure.

Comment: I'm coming at this from the standpoint of someone who implements allocators quite often though for very low-level systems with a focus on data-oriented design. In that case the data structure and allocator start to become a bit of a blur -- at least you learn to see them as strongly connected to each other, and the memory layout that results at the end of the day. One of my pet peeves is that linked lists are often dismissed as poor for performance -- they don't have to be if we can get back the control over memory that we'd normally lose if we just `malloc` every node individually.

Comment: Since comments are not meant to be permanent can you add a description of next and prev extraction would work in your answer.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Not exactly what you asked for, but I've just added an example of traversing through the list.

Comment: An XOR-linked-list has one huge advantage over a normal double-linked list: It is position-independent.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I am not quite sure what you mean by "position-independent", since obviously the value of `ptr` here is very much dependent on the position of the node in the list... I suppose this is not the position you were alluding to?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Try mapping the whole list to an arbitrary place in your program, and all the nodes still work. That's the kind of position-independence I mean.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Ah! I see. Indeed, it could for example work within a single shared memory area.

Comment: To walk to the next or previous item in the list, it appears that code _must_ start walking the list from the beginning or the end.  I do not see how code, given a pointer to some element in the list, could determine the previous or next element.

Comment: @chux You need pointers to two adjacent nodes if you want to start from the middle of the list.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat +1 for using uintptr_t instead of real pointers. You should add a warning that using real pointers is uundefined behavior and that the solution will not work on some systems and compilers, especially with garbage collectors (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14244071/5581200 )

Answer (score 18):

I'd like to offer an alternative answer which boils down to "yes and no".

First, it's *"sort of impossible"* if you want to get the full benefits of a doubly-linked list with only one single pointer per node.

**XOR List**

Yet cited here was also the XOR linked list. It retains one main benefit by having a lossy compression of two pointers fitting into one that you lose with a singly-linked list: the ability to traverse it in reverse. It cannot do things like remove elements from the middle of the list in constant-time given only the node address, and being able to go back to a previous element in a forward iteration and removing an arbitrary element in linear time is even simpler without the XOR list (you likewise keep two node pointers there: `previous` and `current`).

**Performance**

Yet also cited in the comments was a desire for *performance*. Given that, I think there are some practical alternatives.

First, a next/prev pointer in a doubly-linked list doesn't have to be, say, a 64-bit pointer on 64-bit systems. It can be two indices into a 32-bit contiguous address space. Now you got two indices for the memory price of one pointer. Nevertheless, trying to emulate 32-bit addressing on 64-bit is quite involved, maybe not exactly what you want.

However, to reap the full performance benefits of a linked structure (trees included) often requires you to get back control over how the nodes are allocated and distributed in memory. Linked structures tend to be bottlenecky because, if you just use `malloc` or plain `operator new` for every node, e.g., you lose control over memory layout. Often (not always -- you can get lucky depending on the memory allocator, and whether you allocate all your nodes at once or not) this means a loss of contiguity, which means a loss of spatial locality.

It's why data-oriented design stresses arrays more than anything else: linked structures are not normally very friendly for performance. The process of moving chunks from larger memory to smaller, faster memory likes it if you are going to access neighboring data within the same chunk (cache line/page, e.g.) prior to eviction.

**The Not-So-Often-Cited Unrolled List**

So there's a hybrid solution here which is not so often discussed, which is the unrolled list. Example:

```
struct Element
{
    ...
};

struct UnrolledNode
{
    struct Element elements[32];
    struct UnrolledNode* prev;
    struct UnrolledNode* next;
};
```

An unrolled list combines the characteristics of arrays and doubly-linked lists all into one. It'll give you back a lot of spatial locality without having to look to the memory allocator.

It can traverse forwards and backwards, it can remove arbitrary elements from the middle at any given time for cheap.

And it reduces the linked list overhead to the absolute minimum: in this case I hard-coded an unrolled array size of 32 elements per node. That means the cost of storing the list pointers has shrunk to 1/32th of its normal size. That's even cheaper from a list pointer overhead standpoint than a singly-linked list, with often faster traversal (because of cache locality).

It's not a perfect replacement for a doubly-linked list. For a start, if you are worried about the invalidation of existing pointers to elements in the list on removal, then you have to start worrying about leaving vacant spaces (holes/tombstones) behind that get reclaimed (possibly by associating free bits in each unrolled node). At that point you're dealing with many similar concerns of implementing a memory allocator, including some minor forms of fragmentation (ex: having an unrolled node with 31 vacant spaces and only one element occupied -- the node still has to stay around in memory to avoid invalidation until it becomes completely empty).

An "iterator" to it which allows insertion/removal to/from the middle typically has to be larger than a pointer (unless, as noted in the comments, you store additional metadata with each element). It can waste memory (typically moot unless you have really teeny lists) by requiring, say, the memory for 32 elements even if you have a list of only 1 element. It does tend to be a little more complex to implement than any of these above solutions. But it's a very useful solution in a performance-critical scenario, and often one that probably deserves more attention. It's one that's not brought up so much in computer science since it doesn't do any better from an algorithmic perspective than a regular linked list, but locality of reference has a significant impact on performance as well in real-world scenarios.

Comment: One thing you could do is take your unrolled list and add a field to each Element which combines a flag saying whether the element is in use and also a number saying which index the Element is within it's parent UnrolledNode object. This would allow you to remove an Element or iterate through the list given only a pointer to an Element.

Comment: That's a nice suggestion and would simplify things a lot -- I think it's practical if `Element` is large enough to make that a rather trivial cost in comparison. Often my biggest temptation to reach for these is when `Element` is small and forms the hot data (emphasis most on fast sequential traversal), while something like a removed status tends to be cold and well-suited to be outside (ex: bit array).

Comment: Err sorry, that comment about the hot/cold distinction was embarrassingly flawed and just for my specific use case. I tend to use these buried under APIs where the clients have to retrieve handles to the data anyway prior to access (often multiple traversals afterwards), and so that kind of used/removal flag tends to be cold in my case, while the elements themselves are pretty hot. Apologies -- (wave hands) -- nothing to see here! In a more direct scenario, the used/removed status would tend to be quite hot and required as part of the traversal.

Comment: @Ike: In any case, for alignment reasons, packing the tombstone flags in a bit array (a single `uint32_t` in your case) outside the elements array is probably a good idea. Don't want to accidentally bump the size of the elements array just for 1 bit per element... It also hints that on a 64 bits system you would probably aim for a 64 elements array.

Comment: Much agreed -- though there might be a flip side where this kind of metadata (index+used/removed bit) might actually be practically "free" padding as part of the optimal alignment of the element. I suppose case-by-case -- but yeah, I like the generality of just a bit array outside (perhaps just because I can more generally apply it without thinking too much about the element rep, and in C++, toss it into a generic container).

Comment: @matthieu-m that is true if you only want a tombstone flag but if you also want the ability to go back from an element pointer to the unrollednode containing it then you need to have a field in the element structure for that purpose. since that field probablly doesn't need very many bits it IMO makes sense to pack the liveness flag in there too.

Comment: It definitely does help for kind of random-access cases (as in cases where you did something based on a previously stored pointer, not sequential) to store metadata of some sort in the element. My use cases are typically restricted with these to favor sequential access above all else (its where packing multiple elements into one unrolled node helps), with random-access cases typically rare enough to warrant storing the metadata with the iterator. But for a balanced kind of general-purpose scenario, it definitely makes sense to have some metadata with each element entry in the unrolled node.

Comment: Another trick that can potentially be exploited provided that `sizeof(Element) >= sizeof(pointer)` is to treat each element's memory as a union between the element data and a `next` pointer. When the element is freed, it can be treated like a pointer and added to a stack. The cost is just one extra head pointer per unrolled node. That doesn't help things like removal from the middle, but it changes things like insertions which reclaim vacant spaces back to a constant-time operation that doesn't have to look through free bits or anything like that.

Comment: @Ike: Note that looking through 32 or 64 bits is a constant-time operation as it does not depend on the number of elements in the sequence. Regarding packing an "index" into the element, a potential trick is using `struct NodeData: Element, Index {}` where the latter only contains a single byte. If there is a spare byte at the end of `Element`, it'll be for free... but I'd personally favor having meta-data in the iterator.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You might know a clever trick that I don't there bitwise. Let's say we have the free bits (just with 8 elements), `11110111` -- how do we deduce, in constant-time, that the 5th bit is free among these, without 8 operations? I can think of a constant-time way to make sure it's completely empty or completely full, and possibly logarithmic techniques to hone in to a specific free bit -- but a technique to extract the position of the first 0 out of there in constant-time eludes me.

Comment: I'm thinking specifically in the case of reclaiming tombstones on subsequent insertions -- to figure out which indices are free within an unrolled node (complexity with respect to the node rather than container) -- or maybe I misunderstood what was meant by "sequence" there -- I honed in to just the unrolled node rather than their aggregate.

Comment: @Ike: First of all, looping over 32 or 64 values is constant time, in that it does not vary depending on the number of elements in the list (that is O(64) = O(1)).  That being said, compilers generally offer built-ins for bit operations (which if available map to equivalent CPU instructions). Finding the first 0 bit of an integer can be accomplished by calling `__builtin_clz` on gcc (count leading zeroes) on the negated integer. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html for a list of plenty of built-ins :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ah, I understand you better now. I was considering purely the time complexity of the unrolled node as though it was a sequence/data structure unto itself -- not the whole unrolled list aggregating it. That's also what I meant by the constant-time distinction with a union -- (constant-time with respect to the unrolled node only). Is it unusual to speak about algorithmic complexity at a faceted level like this? It's been a long time since CS -- I tend to think about time complexity as contextual, breaking down into granular levels (albeit perhaps not right).

Comment: Oh well, more practically -- I should perhaps just say, the union approach needs no loop -- at least without that `__builtin_clz` intrinsic (which I have to check out further!).

Comment: Something you said made my brain short-circuit a bit there. I think there is something I've misunderstood about time complexity for embarrassingly years now that I need to revisit and relearn. I've let a lot of those little data structure choices influence my understanding of complexity -- and don't really understand how to properly describe, say, the insertion of a unique child into a singly-linked child list for a k-ary tree node when the list size is bounded by k, a constant. I would have always described it as "linear" with a loop, with the tree operation as a whole being logarithmic.

Comment: @Ike: O(...) in itself does not mean anything more than 1 or 2, it's just a quantity without unit. In order to be fully formal, one should thus specify the quantity, for example insertion in a binary search tree of N elements is O(log N) *comparisons*. I am afraid we were a bit sloppy earlier, and thus ended up talking past each others as we each had our own units in mind... Beyond unit, note that the O(...), o(...) and Θ(...) notations express the algorithmic complexity when N tends toward infinity. I do not think they should really be used for bounded quantities normally.

Answer (score 8):

It's not completely possible. A doubly linked list requires two pointers, one for the link in each direction.

Depending on what you need the XOR linked list may do what you need (see HolyBlackCat's answer).

Another option is to work around this limitation a little by doing things like remembering the last node you processed as you iterate through the list. This will let you go back one step during the processing but it doesn't make the list doubly linked.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare and support two initial pointers to nodes `head` and `tail`. In this case you will be able to add nodes to the both ends of the list.

Such a list sometimes called a two-sided list.

However the list itself will be a forward list.

Using such a list you can for example simulate a queue.

Comment: While suitable for *some* applicatoins of doubly linked lists, this does not have O(1) backwards iteration, O(1) insertion at pointed-to position, O(1) deletion at pointed-to position. -- One could even get rid of *all* pointers if one wanted to implement a queue of bounded length ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It does not has backward iterations And I said about this in my answer. So you comment does not make any sense.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Actually, it has O(1) insertion/deletion at any position... but you need to give the position of the element *prior* to the one you wish to remove.

Comment: it's a deque really.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in a portable way without invoking undefined behavior:
[Can an XOR linked list be implemented in C++ without causing undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243971/can-an-xor-linked-list-be-implemented-in-c-without-causing-undefined-behavior)