# Why does std::list::reverse have O(n) complexity?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, linked-list

Why does the reverse function for the `std::list` class in the C++ standard library have linear runtime? I would think that for doubly-linked lists the reverse function should have been O(1).

Reversing a doubly-linked list should just involve switching the head and the tail pointers.

Comment: I do not understand why people are downvoting this question. It is a perfectly reasonable question to ask.  Reversing a doubly linked list should take O(1) time.

Comment: unfortunately, some folks confuse the concepts of "the question is good" with "the question has a good idea". I love questions like  this, where basically "my understanding seems different than a commonly accepted practice, please help resolve this conflict", because expanding how you think helps you solve a lot more problems down the road! It would appear others take the approach of "that's a waste of processing in 99.9999% of cases, don't even think about it". If it's any consolation, I've been downvoted for much, much less!

Comment: Yeah this question got an inordinate amount of downvotes for its quality. Probably it's the same as who upvoted Blindy's answer. In fairness, "reversing a doubly linked list should just involve switching the head and tail pointers" is generally not true for the standard linked list impl that everyone learns in highschool, or for many implementations that people use. A lot of times in SO people's immediate gut reaction to the question or answer drives upvote / downvote decision. If you had been more clear in that sentence or omitted it, I think you would have gotten less downvotes.

Comment: Do you mean you expect this to work? http://ideone.com/L15SjI

Comment: Or let me put the burden of proof with you, @Curious: I have whipped up a doubly linked list implementation here: http://ideone.com/c1HebO. Can you indicate how you would expect the `Reverse` function to be implemented in O(1)?

Comment: @CompuChip: Please read the current top answers to understand how it would be achieved: [Ami Tavory's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35612350/147192) or [5gon12eder's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35612583/147192).

Comment: @MatthieuM. that involves more than just "switching the head and the tail pointers". I just wanted to make sure that the OP didn't have anything else in mind given their apparently strong opinion on some of the answers.

Comment: @CompuChip: Actually, depending on the implementation, it may not. You do not need an extra boolean to know which pointer to use: just use the one not pointing back to you... which could well be automatic with a XOR'ed linked list by the way. So yes, it depends on how the list is implemented, and the OP statement could be clarified.

Comment: Saying that you can test the links (even for an XOR list) rather than checking a boolean does not contradict the point made by Avi Tavory's answer, @MatthieuM.: there is an extra comparison being made.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Sure... and I certainly never tried to imply otherwise (and apologize if it was confusing). To be fully honest, I am actually unclear on whether a XOR'ed list could be reverse in O(1) and would need a test; it might, it might not, I have not fully worked it out... because it seems pointless to. Who cares, really? ;)

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Hypothetically, `reverse` could have been *O(1)*. There (again hypothetically) could have been a boolean list member indicating whether the direction of the linked list is currently the same or opposite as the original one where the list was created.

Unfortunately, that would reduce the performance of basically any other operation (albeit without changing the asymptotic runtime). In each operation, a boolean would need to be consulted to consider whether to follow a "next" or "prev" pointer of a link.

Since this was presumably considered a relatively infrequent operation, the standard (which does not dictate implementations, only complexity), specified that the complexity could be linear. This allows "next" pointers to always mean the same direction unambiguously, speeding up common-case operations.

Comment: I'm not satisfied with this answer. Couldn't the same argument be made to any operation on any container? For example, theoretically, `sort` could be *O(1)* as well if you keep a boolean member indicating whether operations should return the value corresponding to the sorted position. Of course, operations on the iterator will be *O(nlog(n))* at least once, but that's just an implementation detail. Basically, you can use the same argument to arbitrarily defer complexity. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MooseBoys I think what you wrote here - with which I completely agree - is exactly the point. You could hypothetically take the most common operation on a container, e.g., iteration, and say that it is not more *O(1)*, but rather *O(n log(n))*, because it might require, say, sorting, while sorting could be *O(1)* due to "lazy" sorts. I guess the art of defining standards is deciding if this makes sense or not.

Comment: @MooseBoys: I don't agree with your analogy. The difference is that, in the case of a list,the implementation could provide `reverse` with `O(1)` complexity **without affecting the big-o of any other operation**, by using this boolean flag trick. But, in practice an extra branch in every operation is costly, even if it is technically O(1). By contrast, you cannot make a list structure in which `sort` is O(1) and all the other operations are the same cost. The point of the question is that, seemingly, you can get `O(1)` reverse for free if you only care about big O, so why didn't they do that.

Comment: Actually, it's more than that. Every node would also need a pointer to the list object itself (to have access to the direction flag), making every node larger. This, in turn, would make splice operations O(n) instead of O(1) (because you'll have to update that pointer in all the nodes in the subsequence).

Comment: If you used an XOR-linked-list, reversing would become constant time. An iterator would be bigger though, and incrementing/decrementing it would be slightly more computationally expensive. That might be dwarfed by the unavoidable memory-accesses though for *any* kind of linked list.

Comment: It seems to me that adding that boolean flag to every node would be a questionable decision from an architectural/design point of view, too. Every operation would "know" something about how `reverse` works, coupling them together and making change more difficult.

Comment: @IlyaPopov: Does every node actually need this? The user never asks any questions of the list node itself, only the main list body. So accessing the boolean is easy for any method that the user calls. You could make the rule that the iterators are invalidated if the list is reversed, and/or store a copy of the boolean with the iterator, for example. So I think it would not affect the big O, necessarily. I'll admit, I didn't go line-by-line through the spec. :)

Comment: @Deduplicator: You can't make an XOR linked list under C++, unless you're willing to sacrifice generality.  Pointers can have trap representations, so just calculating the XOR of two pointers is not guaranteed to be legal.

Comment: @Kevin: Hm, what? You cannot xor two pointers directly anyway, you need to convert them to integers first (obviously of type `std::uintptr_t`. *Then* you can xor them.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Like I said, you have to sacrifice generality.  `std::uintptr_t` is an optional type.  The implementation is not required to provide it.

Comment: @Dave: If you did add the boolean flag to every node, then to reverse the list, you'd have to invert the flag in every node, so the reversal would be back to O(n). Likewise, if you put it into each iterator, then reversing would become O(M), (linear on the number of active iterators) *and* the list would need to store an ancillary list of all currently active iterators, so when you reverse the list, you can go find all the iterators and change the flag in each.

Comment: @Kevin, you definitely could make an XOR linked list in C++, it's practically the poster-child language for this kind of thing. Nothing says you have to use `std::uintptr_t`, you could cast to a `char` array and then XOR the components. It would be slower but 100% portable. Likely you could make it select between these two implementations and only use the second as a fallback if `uintptr_t` is missing. Some if it is described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243971/can-an-xor-linked-list-be-implemented-in-c-without-causing-undefined-behavior

Comment: @ChrisBeck: It's not legal to subtract pointers to unrelated objects.  Pointers can be segmented, or arbitrary structs.  Subtraction is only required to work for pointers into the same array and other such things.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, user code is limited by portability etc. However, we're talking standard library (part of implementation) here. They can use all the platform-specifics, undefined behaviour etc. they want - they know it.

Comment: @Kevin: Subtle difference: I think it's totally legal to subtract pointers to unrelated objects. It's just illegal to dereference said pointer.  But I _think_ `*(&x- &y+&y)` is legal.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Nope, see 5.7/7: "For addition or subtraction, if the expressions P or Q have type “pointer to cv T”, where T is different from
the cv-unqualified array element type, the behavior is undefined." The two different objects could be stored in two different types of memory, where subtraction just doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's noteworthy that a direction boolean can be trivially wrapped around the simpler `std::list` if this O(1) reverse is wanted, but if the standard implementation always provided such a boolean then the cost is there wanted or not (unless provided by e.g. a template policy, but then interfaces wanting to handle `std::list<>` instantiations would need two overloads or to themselves be made polymorphic etc....)

Comment: This is the case where you should revert to a traditional C.

Answer (score 61):

It *could* be *O*(1) if the list would store a flag that allows swapping the meaning of the “`prev`” and “`next`” pointers each node has. If reversing the list would be a frequent operation, such an addition might be in fact useful and I don't know of any reason why implementing it would be *prohibited* by the current standard. However, having such a flag would make ordinary *traversal* of the list more expensive (if only by a constant factor) because instead of

```
current = current->next;
```

in the `operator++` of the list iterator, you would get

```
if (reversed)
  current = current->prev;
else
  current = current->next;
```

which is not something you'd decide to add easily. Given that lists are usually traversed much more often than they are reversed, it would be very unwise for the standard to *mandate* this technique. Therefore, the reverse operation is allowed to have linear complexity. Do note, however, that *t* ∈ *O*(1) ⇒ *t* ∈ *O*(*n*) so, as mentioned earlier, implementing your “optimization” technically would be permitted.

If you come from a Java or similar background, you might wonder why the iterator has to check the flag each time. Couldn't we instead have two distinct iterator types, both derived from a common base type, and have `std::list::begin` and `std::list::rbegin` polymorphically return the appropriate iterator? While possible, this would make the whole thing even worse because advancing the iterator would be an indirect (hard to inline) function call now. In Java, you're paying this price routinely anyway, but then again, this is one of the reasons many people reach for C++ when performance is critical.

As pointed out by [Benjamin Lindley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440119/benjamin-lindley) in the comments, since `reverse` is not allowed to invalidate iterators, the only approach permitted by the standard seems to be to store a pointer back to the list inside the iterator which causes a double-indirect memory access.

Comment: Do you really need a flag per node? It seems that if you have a flag per list, this is OK. Since reversing the list invalidates iterators anyway

Comment: The test would behave very well with branch prediction, so I'm not sure they would be any noticeable overhead anyway.

Comment: If you have a flag per list, you need a pointer in the iterator back to its list. Besides the fact that this would mean a doubly indirect load, a pointer costs even more memory than a boolean. As for the branch prediction: Under lucky circumstances, it could probably mitigate a good deal of the cost, but I wouldn't assume it can make the check gratis.

Comment: @galinette: `std::list::reverse` does not invalidate iterators.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Good point, so you'd actually *have* to take the double indirection approach.

Comment: @galinette Sorry, I mis-read your earlier comment as “flag per *iterator*” as opposed to “flag per *node*” as you wrote it. Of course, a flag per *node* would be counter-productive as you would, again, have to do a linear traversal to flip them all.

Comment: @5gon12eder: You could eliminate the branching at very lost cost: store the `next` and `prev` pointers in an array, and store the direction as a `0` or `1`. To iterate forward, you'd follow `pointers[direction]` and to iterate in reverse `pointers[1-direction]` (or vice versa). This would still add a tiny bit of overhead, but *probably* less than a branch.

Comment: You probably can't store a pointer to the list inside the iterators.  `swap()` is specified to be constant time and not invalidate any iterators.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Damn it! Well, triple indirection then… (I mean, not actually triple. You'd have to store the flag in a dynamically allocated object but the pointer in the iterator can of course point directly to that object instead of indirecting over the list.)

Comment: The iterator invalidation thing is probably the main point here. Iterator stability is pretty much the number 1 reason to pick a list over a vector.

Answer (score 37):

Surely since all containers that support bidirectional iterators have the concept of rbegin() and rend(), this question is moot?

It's trivial to build a proxy that reverses the iterators and access the container through that.

This non-operation is indeed O(1).

such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

template<class Container>
struct reverse_proxy
{
    reverse_proxy(Container& c)
    : _c(c)
    {}

    auto begin() { return std::make_reverse_iterator(std::end(_c)); }
    auto end() { return std::make_reverse_iterator(std::begin(_c)); }

    auto begin() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(std::end(_c)); }
    auto end() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(std::begin(_c)); }

    Container& _c;
};

template<class Container>
auto reversed(Container& c)
{
    return reverse_proxy<Container>(c);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    list<string> l { "the", "cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat" };

    auto r = reversed(l);
    copy(begin(r), end(r), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
mat
the
on
sat
cat
the
```

Given this, it seems to me that the standards committee have not taken time to mandate O(1) reverse-ordering of the container because it's not necessary, and the standard library is largely built on the principle of mandating only what is strictly necessary while avoiding duplication.

Just my 2c.

Answer (score 18):

Because it has to traverse every node (`n` total) and update their data (the update step is indeed `O(1)`). This makes the whole operation `O(n*1) = O(n)`.

Comment: Because you need to update the links between every item too. Take out a piece of paper and draw it out instead of downvoting.

Comment: no you don't.  It is a doubly linked list.  I downvoted and provided an explanation of my downvote.  your answer is not exhaustive and does not answer my question.

Comment: Why ask if you're so sure then? You're wasting both our time.

Comment: @Curious Doubly linked list's nodes have a sense of direction. Reason from there.

Comment: @Blindy A good answer should be complete. "Take out a piece of paper and draw it out" thus should not be a requisite component of a good answer. Answers which are not good answers are subject to downvotes.

Comment: @Shoe: Do they have to? Please research XOR-linked-list and the like.

Comment: @Deduplicator Wouldn't the need for a history to determine the address to an adjacent node classify the XOR approach as a queue instead of a list? Removing a node would be a linear operation instead of a constant operation with XOR addressing.

Comment: @Snowhawk04: no. please research XOR-linked list, that's not how it works. The point is that when you iterate, your "iterator" is actually a pair of pointers to adjacent nodes. There is no need for a history, and XOR linked list is definitely not a queue.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: I assume that it would be difficult to [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) items without invalidating iterators in such an iterator-is-a-pair XOR-list setup.

Answer (score 2):

It also swaps previous and next pointer for every node. Thats why it takes Linear. Although it can be done in O(1) if the function using this LL also takes information about LL as input like whether it is accessing normally or reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Only an algorithm explanation. 
Imagine you have an array with elements, then you need to inverted it.
The basic idea is to iterate on each element changing the element on the
first position to the last position, the element on second position to penultimate position, and so on. When you reach at the middle of the array you'll have all elements changed, thus in (n/2) iterations, which is considered O(n).

Answer (score 1):

It is O(n) simply because it needs to copy the list in reverse order.  Each individual item operation is O(1) but there are n of them in the entire list.

Of course there are some constant-time operations involved in setting up the space for the new list, and changing pointers afterwards, etc.  The O notation doesn't consider individual constants once you include a first-order n factor.