# XOR Linked List XOR Function

Tags: c, linked-list, xor

I came across this piece of code several times while looking at the implementation of XOR Linked Lists , but none of them seemed to explain this line properly (or maybe I missed out something) -

```
struct node* XOR (struct node *a, struct node *b)
{
    return (struct node*) ((unsigned int) (a) ^ (unsigned int) (b));
}
```

**How does it work ? Can anyone please explain the casts involved too ?**(please point out any previous answers/comments which have described it) Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [C code for XOR linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531972/c-code-for-xor-linked-list)

Comment: @aruisdante Thanks!! But for this specific line the second answer seemed a little complicated.

Comment: The short answer is that it's taking the address of ``a``, the address of ``b``, and ``xor``ing them together to get the address of a third node (you can't ``xor`` pointers directly, hence the cast to ``int``). This would be a complete non-nonsensical thing to do unless you had a lot of guarantees about the memory address of the nodes in the list, which I assume a properly constructed XOR linked-list does.

Comment: `(a^b) ^ a == b`, and `(a^b) ^ b == a`. Consider what that means when one is a pointer to "this node" and the other is the XOR of the pointer to "this node" and a pointer to "some other node". And this really should be using `uintptr_t`, btw. Still platform dependent but stands a fighting chance

Comment: @aruisdante The XOR part seems fine , but how does it work even without the cast ? i.e , **return ((unsigned int) (a) ^ (unsigned int) (b));**

Comment: Basically, it lets you create a doubly-linked-list using only a single pointer by leveraging parity and carefully selected memory locations. And it works because in C ``int`` and a pointer are implicitly convertible.

Comment: @aruisdante - **Implicitly convertible** , that is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @aruisdante - One more thing , is the explicit conversion just to be sure ? Or it has some other purpose too ?

Comment: Nope, just to make it more stylistically consistent and clear that the method was indeed intending to recast to ``node*``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the usual XOR performed on the addresses pointed by the 'a' and the 'b' pointers

```
(unsigned int) (a) ^ (unsigned int) (b)
```

it is the **implicit conversion of int to pointer** (*struct node ** here) that makes this code work.

```
(struct node *)(unsigned int someInteger);
```

***EDIT*** : Thanks to @aruisdante for explaining the second part !

Comment: I think it's worth noting that if the size of a pointer is different from the size of an integer, you run into information loss/integer overflow/undefined behavior. You should instead use `uintptr_t` as @WhozCraig mentioned.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen - Thanks for the information ! So what you mean to say is , suppose _struct node_ had multiple fields, then the cast could actually go wrong ?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with that. If the size of a ``pointer`` (doesn't mater what it's pointing to, they're all the same size) is different from the size of an ``int``, you can have loss of information going either direction in the cast (though, with XOR, as long as ``int > ptr``, you're generally safe). For example, if on a particular machine ``int`` is 16bits, but ``ptr`` is 32bits, this method will fail completely for addresses that have information in the upper 16 bits of the pointer address.